# How can I store per query user signals in solr, then boost by them at query time

Tags: solr, signals

We currently have an application that is heavily search focused, and we are looking to include user signals (clicks/downloads/etc) into our search results. We want to do this on a per keyword basis to really improve relevance and tune our search results.

We have a model with the following schema

```
Resource
id
title
description
tags
```

and I want to do something like

```
ResourceSignals
resource_id
search_term
boost_amount
```

Then at query time resources should be dynamically boosted for a given term by the boost amount (which I would aggregate from clicks at index time). How can I achieve this with solr?

Answer (score 0):

look at [SOLR-10359](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-10359) for the work that recently started on this front.

Another thing you could try is applying [Learning To Rank](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Learning+To+Rank) by using the user feedback too. This is available now.